# Create a 'results' array based on comparison of two two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array, array-difference

I have two two-dimensional arrays I'd liked to compare to one another:

```
$array1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => GB
            [B] => Harry
            [C] => British Army
            [D] => Eton College
            [E] => Cressida Bonas
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => GB
            [B] => William
            [C] => Royal Air Force
            [D] => Eton College
            [E] => Catherine Middleton
        )

)

$array2
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => GB
            [B] => Harry
            [C] => British Army
            [D] => Eton College
            [E] => Cressida Bonas
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => GB
            [B] => James
            [C] => British Army
            [D] => Millfield
            [E] => Unknown
        )

)
```

And produce a boolean true/false results array as follows if any of the child array values differ:

```
$results_array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => false      
        )

)
```

**UPDATE:**
Both arrays will always have the same length parent arrays (but the child arrays values may vary in length).

I can't wrap my head around how to use `foreach` in a recursive manner to get the results array.

Any general ideas or advice?

Comment: What data would you like the results array to contain? Correct me if I'm wrong - you want the results array to contain a subarray of duplicate values and another with different values?

Comment: Dump the two arrays using `var_export` and update your question.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon I'd like the results array to contain a boolean true or false data type depending on whether any of sub arrays are duplicates or not. e.g true for duplicates, and false for different. Will update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Excuse my ignorance (still very new to arrays and foreach), but why would I dump the arrays with var_export? How does this help?

Comment: @ElijahPaul Does it matter the order of items? or once a set of items is in both arrays it's duplicate?

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon No the order doesn't matter for the child array values. Actually the child arrays are generated by another script, so if they're duplicates the order will always be the same.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a single element array with a boolean; why not just `[0 => true, 0 => false]` as output?

Comment: @ElijahPaul Check I have posted an answer that will work to check if values are duplicated

Comment: @Jack That's a good question. I have to merge the results array with another two-dimensional array once it's generated. Would I not get an 'off' result if it's a single element array, or then have to convert it? Correct me if I'm wrong? Am still new to this.

Comment: @ElijahPaul, I mentioned `var_export` format because that will make easier for us to work with the arrays.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Just tried `var_export`. I see what you mean. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you tried my answer, btw? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do using `==` operator. Passing the first array as key-array (`$k=>$arr`) [since the value is another array]. Now compare the two arrays using the simple `==` comparison operator. You can even perform strict matching using the `===` operator.

```
<?php
$arr1=array(0=>array('A'=>'GB','B'=>'Harry','C'=>'British Army'),1=>array('A'=>'GB','B'=>'William','C'=>'Royal Air Force'));
$arr2=array(0=>array('A'=>'GB','B'=>'Harry','C'=>'British Army'),1=>array('A'=>'GB','B'=>'James','C'=>'British Army'));

foreach($arr1 as $k=>$arr)
{
    $resarr[][$k]=($arr==$arr2[$k])? "true" : "false";
}
print_r($resarr);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/107763)

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => false
        )

)
```

Comment: Will try this in a minute. Looks like what I was trying to formulate in my head, but couldn't quite get.

Comment: This will not work if the keys are not the same. For example, if you have array1(1=>"Harry", 2=>"Paul") and array2(1=>"Paul", 2=>"Harry"); This answer will return false, even though these arrays are duplicates of each other

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon, Can't you see I have mentioned the `===` operator as an alternate  ??? **Read the answer properly before commenting.**

Comment: Yes I saw, I'm just pointing out a case in which this will not work.

Comment: You are still not getting it. Sad.. I can't comment anymore on this.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Works well. Simple too. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do with a `foreach` loop. Are you saying every array will have `2 child arrays` or every child array will have `5 values`? Regardless, I hope this helps you!

I would use some of these:

- `array_intersect`
- `array_intersect_assoc`
- `array_diff`
- `array_diff_assoc`

Code:

```
<?php

$array1 = [
    [
        'A' => 'GB',
        'B' => 'Harry',
        'C' => 'British Army',
        'D' => 'Eton College',
        'E' => 'Cressida Bonas',
    ],
    [
        'A' => 'GB',
        'B' => 'William',
        'C' => 'Royal Air Force',
        'D' => 'Eton College',
        'E' => 'Catherine Middleton',
    ]
];

// What Values are in common
$result1 = array_intersect_assoc($array1[0], $array1[1]);
print_r($result1);

$array2 = [
    [
        'A' => 'GB',
        'B' => 'Harry',
        'C' => 'British Army',
        'D' => 'Eton College',
        'E' => 'Cressida Bonas',
    ],
    [
        'A' => 'GB',
        'B' => 'James',
        'C' => 'British Army',
        'D' => 'Millfield',
        'E' => 'Unknown',
    ]
];

// What values are different
$result2 = array_diff_assoc($array2[0], $array2[1]);
print_r($result2);


// A Way to check numerically
$perfectMatch = 5;
$intersect = array_intersect_assoc($array1[0], $array1[1]);
$intersectCount = count($intersect);
if ($intersectCount != $perfectMatch) {
    echo "<br> Not Every value matches.";
} else {
    echo "<br> Perfect Match!";
}
```

To compare the full arrays `$array1` and `$array2` you can do:

```
<?php 

// (With array code above)

$c1 = count($array1);
$c2 = count($array2);
if ($c1 != $c2) {
    echo "<br>Array Children must be the same";
}

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $c1; $i++) {
    $in_common = array_intersect($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
    $result[] = count($intersect);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Will clarify my question. The child arrays may vary, but the parent arrays will always be constant.

Comment: Thanks, added a way to compare the groups. In that case you wouldn't need to verify the array children count :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), assuming both arrays are of the same length:

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    return [$a == $b]; // create single element boolean array
}, $array1, $array2);
```

You can use either `==` or `===`; the former (`==`) will yield `true` if both arrays have the same key and value pairs, whereas the latter (`===`) will only yield `true` if the keys of both arrays are also in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers use the == operator; however that will not work if the arrays do not have the same key=>value matchings; Try this:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i => $subarray)
{
    /* No need to proceed if subarray[i] does not exist in the second array */
    if(!is_array($array2[$i]))
    {
        $results[$i] = false;
        continue;
    }        
    $results[$i] = (count(array_diff($array1[$i], $array2[$i])) == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

This solution is a bit slower than using the == comparison operator. However using the == will not work for a case like:

```
$array1 => array(1 => "John", 2 => "James");
$array2 => array(1 => "James", 2 => "John");
```

Here, the keys are not the same, but the values are duplicated. Solutions using == will return false when comparing these arrays.

```
$array1 == $array2     // False
```

Comment: This solution is definitely an overkill.  a `count` , an `is_array()` check and an `array_diff`. These are not at all required , you are just complicating the solution.

Comment: It does in fact have some extra overhead, but works for all cases. If you can find a better/faster solution including solving the case where keys are not in the same order even if there is a duplicate array, please post it. This is all I came up with.